# Does water retain an electric current after an electric current is passed through it?

Tags: electricity

Does water retain an electric current after an electric current is passed through it ?

Comment: Not clear. Please provide some context and explanation for your question. What situation are you asking about? Why do you think that water might retain an electric current?

Answer (score 1):

If I am interpreting your question right, then no.

Firstly, pure water has no conductivity whatsoever. Tap water, however, is slightly conductive due to the ions dissolved in it. So, just for the sake of argument, then we will be using tap water.

Electric current is measured in Amps. Amps are equal to Volts divided by Ohms. Think of volts as the "push", while ohms are the resistance (literally) - the higher the resistance, the less effective the push, and thus the current is weaker. The current in our case must come from a "push", which usually comes from a electrical potential difference induced by a battery. Our resistance is quite high, so our current will be quite small. When we stop pushing (shut off the battery), the value for amps is 0, so there will be no current.